# PackStack issues with neutron router-gateway-set

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

Using centos 6.5

I'm setting up PackStack on a single node with one network interface.

I'm following these instructions http://openstack.redhat.com/Quickstart

That works fine then I get to http://openstack.redhat.com/Floating_IP_range

my network is 192.168.1.0/24  I have one interface eth0  and my gateway is 192.168.1.1
I want to create instances in openstack that is on this network and can talk to other machines on the same network.

This is where I get stuck.

$ neutron net-create thepublic --router:external=True
Created a new network:

| admin_state_up            | True                                 |
| id                        | 28da3a02-25de-45b3-a582-8f5dc29eb864 |
| name                      | thepublic                            |
| provider:network_type     | local                                |
| provider:physical_network |                                      |
| provider:segmentation_id  |                                      |
| router:external           | True                                 |
| shared                    | False                                |
| status                    | ACTIVE                               |
| subnets                   |                                      |
| tenant_id                 | 4acbdfa5ff02412aaa63caa99688010a     |

$ neutron subnet-create thepublic 192.168.1.0/24 --name vlan --enable_dhcp False --allocation_pool start=192.168.1.57,end=192.168.1.62 --gateway 192.168.1.1
Created a new subnet:

| allocation_pools | {"start": "192.168.1.57", "end": "192.168.1.62"} |
| cidr             | 192.168.1.0/24                                   |
| dns_nameservers  |                                                  |
| enable_dhcp      | False                                            |
| gateway_ip       | 192.168.1.1                                      |
| host_routes      |                                                  |
| id               | a219fb59-ccc2-482f-86c4-977d715707e9             |
| ip_version       | 4                                                |
| name             | vlan                                             |
| network_id       | 28da3a02-25de-45b3-a582-8f5dc29eb864             |
| tenant_id        | 4acbdfa5ff02412aaa63caa99688010a                 |

$ neutron router-gateway-set thepublic a219fb59-ccc2-482f-86c4-977d715707e9
Unable to find router with name 'thepublic'

What values am I supposed to use for $ neutron router-gateway-set $router_id $vlan_id

Another thing is I can create instances but can not get those instances to connect to my 192.168.1.0/24 network.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999116/routing-in-openstack/26045634#26045634

All the needed steps are mentioned here

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't actually created a router.
The Openstack Documentation, has vastly improved and the steps are here: 
http://docs.openstack.org/icehouse/install-guide/install/yum/content/neutron-initial-networks.html

Are you installing this on baremetal, or are you trying something out with VirtualBox?  I think you may hit issues using a single interface, although I guess it's possible.

Are you using VLAN, GRE?